# What are the differences between various SSH methods in Google Cloud Compute Engine?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I usually SSH into a Google Cloud Compute Engine Instance using my local terminal like:

`ssh -i ~/.ssh/[KEY_FILENAME [USERNAME]@ip_address`

where the [KEY_FILENAME] is generated using

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/[KEY_FILENAME] -C [USERNAME]`

There is also another way to connect to the instance which is through the browser, however I would connect to the instance with a different user account. Is there a way that I can make it consistent regardless of the method I use to connect?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to connect a Linux instance via the SSH. The way you are connecting to an instance is via the [terminal](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#thirdpartytools). You can connect via the [Cloud Console Web UI](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#gcetools) which is in general the most convenient way to connect to an instance. Also, you can use [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/) and run below command to connect to an instance via SSH:

> gcloud compute ssh [INSTANCE_NAME]

You can also use [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/) to connect your instance from the Cloud Console web UI by using the same command as above. You can connect via the [serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#connectserialconsole) using the Google Cloud Platform Console, the gcloud command-line tool, or a third-party SSH client. The serial console authenticates users with SSH keys. Specifically, you must add your public SSH key to the project or instance metadata, and store your private key on the local machine from which you want to connect. There are other advanced methods to connect to an instance which you can find at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced).

By default, the gcloud compute command-line tool uses the $USER variable to add users to the /etc/passwd file for connecting to virtual machine instances using SSH. You can specify a [different user](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/general-tips#sshusers) using the --ssh-key-file PRIVATE_KEY_FILE flag when running the gcloud compute ssh command. Depending on your use case and convenience, you can use any method consistently.